# gpsd and chrony single gps pps setup

Tags: networking, server, time, ntp, gps

I have a system that will be offline most of the time. I have gpsd and chrony setup, and am able to share gps and pps with chrony via the shared memory. my goal is to make sure the server can share and sync that time to other stations on that local network. What config settings are necessary to achieve both client and server setup? i have allow set in the server setup and i see the "Server" setting that i needs to be set on the client with the servers IP and "prefer iburst". Is there anything else that needs to be set to make this happen with accurate sync?

Answer (score 0):

I have close to the same setup.

In order to make a server you will need to uncomment the line:

```
#Allow to be a NTP server 
allow 192.168.1.0/24
```

Of course you would pick the correct subnet.

and for the client you would need to add:

```
server X.X.X.X
```

with X being your server IP or hostname